# What is the name of this key in Android?

Tags: javascript, android, html, mobile, frontend

I would like to know the name of this key in Android keyboard below.

[image]

I would like to add to the following jQuery method to prevent form submission or tab transition.

**JavaScript**:

```
const blockEnter = () => {
  $('input').keydown(function(e){
    if( e.key == 'Enter' || e.code == 'Enter' || e.key === "Tab" || e.code === "Tab" ) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  });
}
```

above function run properly on the desktop and iPhone(safari)

#### Environment

- Android
- Google Chrome browser

Comment: Try doing `alert(e.key)` or `alert(e.code)`, then run it on the phone, it'll give you something you can then look up - maybe, if the keydown event fires at all for that key

Comment: I put `alert(e.key)` and `alert(e.code)` in keydown function then ran on the phone, but the keydown event doesn't fire. I assume that the keydown event does not detect this key, so I will look it up.

Comment: Might be a better idea to wrap the input within a `form` element. This would give you the `submit` event (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit_event). You would even have to check for the keycode if you went down this route.